# Anti-alias text disabled only in terminal

Tags: terminal, fonts

I find the anti-aliased fonts really difficult to read in the terminal. I have been able to disable anti-aliasing across the board by using the `~/.fonts.cnf` file. This makes using everything else much less pleasant however.

Can anyone tell me how to disable anti-aliasing only in the command prompt?

This is on a Raspberry Pi, if that makes a difference.

Using lxterminal, which allows you to set the font, and its size, but not its aliasing.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm unsure of the difference, it's the terminal on the desktop.

Comment: First you say "Anti-alias text only in terminal" and "I find the alaised fonts really difficult to read in the terminal", meaning that you do want to have anti-aliased text. Later you say the opposite: "how to disable anti-aliasing only in the command prompt". Please edit the question to clarify which direction you want.

Answer (score -1):

Basicly text antialiasing is smoothing procudure which makes text more readable and nice but it needs some computing power to do that.If you have low performence computer then you want to disable text aliasing because computer will work faster and it will has positive impact on baterry working time.
To disable globally text antialiasing on Ubuntu you should open console / terminal and type: cd /etc/fonts/conf.d. When you are in conf.d then open file 10-antialias.conf by typing command sudo nano 10-antialias.conf and put your user password to edit the file.

In file you can find code like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
    <fontconfig>
    <!-- Use the Antialiasing -->
        <match target="pattern">
            <edit name="antialias" mode="append"><bool>true</bool>
        </match>
    </fontconfig>
```

Go to line true and change true for false. Save the file (Ctr+X and Y). The last thing you should do is computer restart to see the diffrence.

Comment: The asker already knows how to disable anti-aliasing globally - the question is how to _selectively_ disable it for specific applications.